# Show that $\frac{1}{t}\int_2^\infty\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{x^2\log x}dx\rightarrow 0$ as $t\rightarrow 0$

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, upper-lower-bounds

> Show that $$\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{1}{t}\int_2^\infty\frac{1-\cos(tx)}{x^2\log x}dx=0$$

This is arising as an intermediate step in a problem.

**My attempts**

I thought bounding this by another function which goes to zero with $t$ will help. But taking the trivial bound $|1-\cos x|\leq 2$ doesn't help. Taking another bound $|{1-\cos x}|\leq\frac{x^2}{2}$ also doesn't help, since $\int_2^\infty\frac{1}{\log x}dx$ is divergent.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you believe this limit exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that we may assume $ t > 0$. Using the inequality that $\cos(x) \geq 1 - x^2/2$, we have

\begin{align*}
0 \leq \frac{1}{t} \int_{2}^{\infty} \frac{1-\cos(tx)}{x^2\log x} \, \mathrm{d}x
&\leq \frac{1}{t} \int_{2}^{1/t} \frac{(tx)^2/2}{x^2\log x} \, \mathrm{d}x + \frac{1}{t} \int_{1/t}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^2\log x} \, \mathrm{d}x \\
&= t \int_{2}^{1/t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log x} + \frac{1}{t} \int_{1/t}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^2\log x} \, \mathrm{d}x. \tag{1}
\end{align*}

For the first term, we can apply L'Hospital's theorem to get

$$ t \int_{2}^{1/t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log x}
= \frac{\int_{2}^{1/t} \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{\log x}}{1/t}
\sim \frac{-1/t^2\log(1/t)}{-1/t^2}
= \frac{1}{\log(1/t)}. $$

Likewise, by the L'Hospital's theorem,

$$ \frac{\int_{1/t}^{\infty} \frac{2}{x^2\log x} \, \mathrm{d}x}{t}
\sim \frac{1/(t^2(1/t)^2\log(1/t))}{1}
= \frac{1}{\log (1/t)}. $$

Therefore the bound $\text{(1)}$ is $\mathcal{O}(1/\log(1/t))$ and converges to $0$ as $t \to 0^+$.

Comment: How can we L'Hospital's rule in the second case? Differentiating in the case of improper integral is unknown to me.

Comment: @Martund First rewrite that integral with $x=1/u$ as $-2\int_0^t\frac{du}{\ln u}$.

Comment: @Martund, There is no issue applying Fundamental Theorem of Calculus for improper integral. Indeed, fix any $2 < a < \infty$ and write $$\int_{x}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2\log u}=\int_{x}^{a}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2\log u}+\int_{a}^{\infty}\frac{\mathrm{d}u}{u^2\log u}.$$ Then note that (1) FToC is applicable to the first integral in the RHS, and (2) the second integral is merely a constant, which does not affect the differentiation.

Comment: Thank you sir for this nice answer!